# Bitcoin cloud trading

Tags: client, trading, investing, marketplace, bots

Is there a trading bots that trades automatically and can also be hosted by the company that is providing the service?

I've found BTCRobot and Butter Bot. Any reviews on the validity behind these companies and maybe some personal experience would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give a general answer here and say any off the shelf BTC trading software is not going to be profitable. Why? Because there's absolutely no reason a functional trading bot would be sold when it could be used to generate income.

Profitable bots would be custom made and not advertised.

Any claims made are dubious at best on these websites.

Comment: In practice you are probably right, but in principle it's a bit more complex.  If there were a bot that produced *risk-free* profit I would agree that nobody would sell it.  But you could imagine a bot that turns a profit *on average*, but at substantial risk.  A developer who was risk-averse might rationally prefer the safe profits from selling the bot over the risky proposition of running it themselves.

Comment: @NateEldredge good distinction. Websites make the claim the bots make $x per hour. That could be true (at the extreme end of truth!) but how does this bot handle more complicated tasks? Ie is the bot *losing 3x* $x once a day?